# GDX Pay IOS Error while testing

Tags: ios, libgdx, in-app-purchase, robovm

I've tried to implement GDX Pay for IOS for the application I am building.
I am using GDXPay 0.7.0 and GDX Version 1.7.1

I have signed out of the appstore in the settings and created user ids in sandbox environment on the itunesconnect to sign in when prompted for IAP.

However, the application crashes at the time of calling installIAP() without giving me a sign in prompt. The sign in prompt however does appear after the application crashes.

Would appreciate any help in this regards. Thanks in advance.

> 2016-01-04 15:24:30.810 IOSLauncher[3511:1011291] [info] IAP: IAP:
>   gdx-pay successfully instantiated. [GdxPay/AppleIOS] Installing
>   purchase observer...
>
> [GdxPay/AppleIOS] Requesting products...
>
> 2016-01-04 15:24:30.864 IOSLauncher[3511:1011291] [debug]
>   IOSApplication: resumed
>
> [GdxPay/AppleIOS] Products successfully received!
>
> [GdxPay/AppleIOS] Purchase observer successfully installed!
>
> [GdxPay/AppleIOS] There are 0 unfinished transactions. Try to
>   finish...
>
> WARN: Failed to call getClassDomain() for the NSError subclass
>   org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSCocoaError
>
> WARN: Failed to call getClassDomain() for the NSError subclass
>   org.robovm.apple.storekit.SKError
>
> [GdxPay/AppleIOS] Transaction failed: Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain
>   Code=0 "You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in
>   Sandbox at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=You are not
>   authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time.}
>
> com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Transaction failed: Error
>   Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=0 "You are not authorized to make
>   purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=You are not authorized to make
>   purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time.}      at
>   com.vxxxxxxs.pxxxxxxxg.app.PxxxxLxxxg$1.handlePurchaseError(PxxxxxLxxxxg.java:70)
>      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleTransactionObserver.updatedTransactions(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java:392)
>      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleTransactionObserver.$cb$paymentQueue$updatedTransactions$(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java)
>      at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)     at
>   org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:395)      at
>   com.vxxxxxs.pxxxxxxxxg.app.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java:42)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Transaction failed: Error
>   Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=0 "You are not authorized to make
>   purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=You are not authorized to make
>   purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time.}     ... 5 more

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sandbox account is still valid in iTunes. I got this error once when I try to use a **deleted** sandbox account to purchase.